# fortran module use wrong

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following is the code skeleton from VASP. My work is that porting it on one new platform. And when I use the compiler of that platform, I got the error. If I comment out the `use m` and I also get "**It must have an explicit interface specified.**"  I just want to make a minimum modification to avoid incurring errors into other parts of the program.

```
module m
interface 
  subroutine a
  end subroutine
end interface

interface 
  subroutine b
  end subroutine
end interface
end module

subroutine a
  use m

  call b
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code as shown, the interface for subroutine `a` defined in the module is accessible inside subroutine `a` via use association.  Because a subprogram already defines an explicit interface for any procedures that it defines, this means that you have two separately defined explicit interfaces for the same procedure accessible in the same scope.  This is a violation of the rules of the language (F2008 12.4.3.2p7).

You can use the ONLY clause on the USE statement to exclude the interface body variant of the subroutines interface from being made accessible by use association inside the subroutine.

```
module m
  interface 
    subroutine a
    end subroutine
  end interface

  interface 
    subroutine b
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

subroutine a
  use m, only: b

  call b
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
module m

contains

subroutine b
    ! code
end subroutine b

subroutine a
    ! code
    call subroutine b
end subroutine a

end module m
```

From what you've posted I don't see any recursion (neither subroutine calls itself, `a` calls `b` but `b` doesn't call `a`) nor any need for it.  Nor do I see a need for explicitly writing `interface` blocks; package the subroutines into a module and let the compiler take care of checking interface specifications and agreement.

Comment: This code is from the VASP, I just want to port it on one platform. The code is OK when using ifort on x86, but get error when using the compiler of that platform. So I just want make a minimum modification in order to avoid incurring some errors into others part of the program that depend on it.